# Definition of a Graph in Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Say that I have a Riemannian $3$-manifold $M$ with metric $g$ and that one then considers a $3$-manifold $\Sigma$ given by a graph $t=f(x)$ inside a warped product space $(M \times \mathbb{R},g + \phi^2 dt^2)$.

Is the function $f$ which is used to define the graph a function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (ie. does it take as its input a vector), or is it a function from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for a function $f:X\to Y$, the graph of $f$ is a subset of $X\times Y$ given by
$$
\text{graph}(f)=\left\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\right\}
$$
Since your graph is a subset of the warped product space $M\times\mathbb{R}$, it makes sense that $f$ would be a function from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$.